# Set properties file values in static block vs. context params

Tags: java, static, servletcontextlistener

In a Java web app, I have several classes which have static methods that require some credentials stored in a properties file.

I was wondering what the preferred method is for retrieving the values in the properties file:

1. Static Block - Have a `static` block in the classes which reads from the properties file and sets the appropriate credentials as class variables.
2. Context Params - Read from the properties file in the `ContextListener` and set the values in a Context Parameter.

The advantage of (1) is that I don't have to pass the credentials into the static methods every time I call them, which is redundant.

The disadvantage of (1) is that I'm reading from the same properties file several times.

(Advantage/disadvantage reversed for case (2))

Comment: Why does (1) need to read the file more than once?

Comment: I have several such files...I guess I can make it a public variable. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: If you have configuration values that need to be accessed from many classes throughout your application, then yes, a quick way would be to provide them as public getters or fields.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Singleton pattern is usually avoided you could use it here to access your properties from everywhere. Also it will have only immutable state, so I think it is ok to use a Singleton here:

```
public final class MyProperties {   
   private final Properties properties;

   private MyProperties(){
       properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(...); // Load your properties here and maybe do some checks
   }

   public static final MyProperties INSTANCE = new MyProperties();

   // Or add some fields/getters instead
   public String getProp(String key){
       return properties.getProperty(key);
   }
}
```

Please note that here the instance is created on startup, but you could also create it lazily when it is first needed. The advantage here is that you will be notified on startup in case the properties file could not be found.

Also you could extend this to check if certain mandatory properties are included and throw an error otherwise and provide some getters for the properties.

Alternatively you could also just have public static fields that are initialized in a static initializer like that:

```
public final class MyProperties {   
    public static final String USERNAME;
    // More fields        

    static {
        // Load your properties here and set the fields accordingly
    }

    private MyProperties() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Static Block** : A block of code ‘{ }’ that runs only one time, and it is run the first time the Constructor or the main() method for that class is called (Sun calls this ‘when the class is initialized‘) [Reference.](http://www.engfers.com/code/static-initializer-block/)

*"I'm reading from the same properties file several times."*. Why and how ?

Comment: Re: "Why and how": because I have several such files which need to make use of values that are in the properties file